# Variable lifetime problem when passed to message channels within threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, lifetime, channel, ownership

I'm writing a Rust program that does the following:

1. Create an array of threads to spawn, each holds a variable which stores the path of a directory:

```rust
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
let handles: Vec<_> = dir_list
        .into_iter()
        .map(|dir_path| {
            let path2 = dir_path.clone();
            let txc = tx.clone();
            thread::spawn(move || func(txc, &Path::new(&path2)))
        })
        .collect();
for h in handles {
        let _ = h.join();
    }
```

2. in `func()`, run a for loop (on each thread) which iterates through the said path with the `walkdir` crate (https://crates.io/crates/walkdir) and sends respective messages via `tx` to receiver:

```rust
    for entry in WalkDir::new(&path) {
        if entry.is_err() {
            tx.send(Err((entry.unwrap_err(), 0)).unwrap());
            continue;
        }
        let entry = entry.unwrap(); // !
        match func2(&entry) {
            Ok(len) => {
                tx.send((entry.file_name(), Ok(len))).unwrap(); // !
            }
            Err(e) => {
                if e != SubDirError { // a custom error
                    tx.send((entry.file_name(), Err(e.into()))).unwrap(); // !
                }
            }
        }
    }
    drop(tx);
```

The compiler complains about lifetime issues with `entry.file_name()`. Seems that the error means it should live throughout the entire function, which is not possible due to the use of a for loop for different directory paths:

```
error[E0597]: `entry` does not live long enough
  --> src/dir.rs:40:26
   |
24 | [<function header, redacted for clarity>]
   |                                    - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
35 |         let entry = entry.unwrap();
   |             ----- binding `entry` declared here
...
40 |                 tx.send((entry.file_name(), Ok(len))).unwrap();
   |                 ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------
   |                 |        |
   |                 |        borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 argument requires that `entry` is borrowed for `'1`
...
53 | }
   | - `entry` dropped here while still borrowed
```

what should I do? If it's impossible to solve due to being an ownership problem with messages and threads, what other alternatives should I try? I need to pass `entry.file_name()` to the channel upon each iteration.

Comment: Please always post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just promote the `Path` returned from `file_name()` to a `PathBuf`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman here `file_name()` actually returns a `&OsStr`

Comment: Ah well, then promote it to `OsString`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by appending `.to_os_string()` to `entry.file_name()`; that is, promote it from `&OsStr` to `OsString`. Turns out that you should send owned types instead of borrowed references in channels, for `Sender`'s lifetime depends on the type (?).